# I need to take database back up database name with date

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-backups

I need to take daily database backups and add the date to the database name - something like this: `Navigate_2017-10-20.bak`.

How can I use the dynamic query with the database name and date?

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT @Date

BACKUP DATABASE [Navigate] 
TO DISK = N'D:\Working\Navigate_'+ @Date +'.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'Navigate-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: Is Date is datetime column if so then you need to convert it in varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the Date to string and create the filename beforehand:

```
DECLARE @Filename NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @FILENAME = N'D:\Working\Navigate_'+ CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126) +'.bak';


BACKUP DATABASE [Navigate] 
TO  DISK = @FILENAME WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'Navigate-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT @Date

BACKUP DATABASE [Navigate] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Working\Navigate_'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),@Date,105) +'.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'Navigate-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(20) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),105)
SELECT @Date
BACKUP DATABASE [Navigate] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Working\Navigate_'+ @Date +'.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'Navigate-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
```